# How to efficiently read the first 1000 bytes of a large file (larger than hundreds of GBs) in .net languages (C# or PowerShell etc)

Tags: .net, file, file-io, bigdata

How to efficiently read the first 1000 bytes of a large file (larger than hundreds of GBs) in .net languages (C# or PowerShell etc)?
I have some binary files with private format and I need to read the first 1000 bytes to get some meta data of those files. Since they are pretty large, I want to know what's the best way to efficient get those information. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the first section into a suitable binary array:

```
var stream = File.OpenRead(fileName);
byte[] binaryHeader = new byte[1000];
int actuallyRead = stream.Read(binaryHeader, 0, binaryHeader.Length);
```

How large the rest of the file is does not really matter.